# WCF: server-side error handling. best practice

Tags: .net, wcf

I write WCF service and want to keep it's activity log: trace, warnings and error messages. The very straight-forward approach is to wrap all contract service code inside `try/catch` sections and write error messages from `catch` part rethrowing service contract error exceptions.

I suppose it would be nice if there would be one code-point to catch all uncaught exceptions instead of dozens `try/catch` sections. It would be also useful to write contract method parameters from that point to provide detailed error information.

Is it possible with WCF?

What is the best practice in organizing error handling inside WCF services?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) interface

It allows an implementer to control the fault message returned to the caller and optionally perform custom error processing such as logging

You can implement your service behavior (see [IServiceBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.aspx) interface) and add your handler to [ChannelDispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.channeldispatcher.aspx) error handlers.

See [WCF Exception Handling with IErrorHandler](http://blog.wadolabs.com/2009/03/wcf-exception-handling-with-ierrorhandler/) for more details.

Comment: This article is no longer available, and I can't find it archived anywhere... do you know anywhere else it was published?

Answer (score 2):

This [article](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/simplifying-wcf-using-exceptions-as-faults/) explains **very well** the different practices and the best one. Long but will probably answer your question.

(Check **Ideal Scenario** if feeling lazy)

**Article URL:** http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/simplifying-wcf-using-exceptions-as-faults/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works in WCF but you may try the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) Event.

Comment: `AppDomain.UnhandledException` is not the place to handle exceptions, only to log them. Because if the exception propagates to that level, the application is going to terminate.